# Faster method for clearing serial port on pyserial

Tags: python, arduino, serial-port

I have a serial port communication between Windows and an Arduino Due board. A camera is sending data over the serial port. Once an image is captured, analog values from potentiometers are read. The application is in real-time, so it happens continuously.

'COM1' is the serial port that reads data from the camera and the potentiometers. The code uses `Serial.close` and `Serial.open` to stop the data stream after retrieving the image. When I try to use `reset_input_buffer()` without closing and opening the serial port, I still get a random sequence of bad data coming in after the image is captured. Does anyone know why? Currently, I use `time.sleep()` method so `Serial.close()` does not get hung up. Is there a faster way to do this?

**python code**

```
def readData(port_dev, width, height, regId=0xD0, regVal=0xD0):
ser = serial.Serial(port_dev, 5000000)
ser.write(bytearray([regId, regVal]))  # tells Arduino to begin capturing
if regId == 0xD0 and regVal == 0xD0:
    dataY = ser.read(size=width * height)
    index = 0
    bitmap = list()
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            Y = dataY[index]
            bitmap.append(Y)
            index += 1
    ser.write(bytearray([0x99, 0x99]))  # Stop reading data
    npimage = np.array(bitmap)
    arrImage = np.resize(npimage, [height, width])
    time.sleep(1)
    ser.reset_input_buffer()
    time.sleep(.5)
    ser.reset_output_buffer()
    time.sleep(.5)
    ser.close()
    ser.open()
    data = getValues(ser)
    ser.close()
    return arrImage, data

def getValues(ser):
    numPoints = 3  # number of datapoints to read
    dataList = [0] * numPoints  # initialize the list we will write to
    ser.write(bytearray([0x09, 0x09]))  # signal arduino to read pot values
    for i in range(0, numPoints):
        data = ser.readline()
        dataList[i] = data
    return dataList
```

**Arduino code**

```
void loop() {
  char buffer_USB[2];
  if(SerialUSB.available() > 0) {
    SerialUSB.readBytes(buffer_USB,2);
    if(buffer_USB[0] == 0xD0 && buffer_USB[1] == 0xD0) {
      captureImg(WIDTH,HEIGHT,0);
      captureImg(WIDTH,HEIGHT,1);
    }
  if(buffer_USB[0] == 0x09 && buffer_USB[1] == 0x09) {
        data1 = analogRead(analogPin1);
        SerialUSB.println(data1);
        data2 = analogRead(analogPin2);
        SerialUSB.println(data2);
        data3 = analogRead(analogPin3);
        SerialUSB.println(data3);
    }
  }
}
```